# Application Insights missing from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-2019

As the title states I cannot find any Application Insights menu's or options in Visual Studio 2019.

Searching has been fruitless and I see no updated documentation from Microsoft around support for Application Insights in Visual Studio 2019.

Is this something that is not available yet?

Comment: Just checked now and I am missing the Application Insights package from the Tool menu. Doing a check of what is installed via the Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Double check what you have installed as part of your Visual Studio 2019 installation. The product required is (aptly named) "Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package"

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.
The Toolbar disappeared when updating Visual Studio 2019 from version 16.0.0 to 16.0.2.

The solution for me was to just enable the Toolbar again.

Go to "Tools/Customize..." and select "Application Insights" in the Toolbars pane (See picture).

[Customize VS Toolbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJuW9.png)

Comment: by default, that toolbar only shows up when debugging, so it might have gotten reset on the update?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, I recently applied some updates and went to Version 16.11.7, and couldn't find my App Insights window anywhere!

I had to rerun the Visual Studio Installer and then modify my install, then on the tab 'Individual Components', check the box to install 'Developer Analytics Tools'.

[image]

Then after a restart, it re-appeared....but was super tiny.

[image]

After dragging it back to a more reasonable place, it was back in action.

[image]